# download image in tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

when i segue to a viewController with tableView, the tableviewcell immediately send a request to the server using the method `fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: handler: (String) -> Void)`. and this method returns a url that link to the image. download it and cache the image `cacheImage` is an object of `NSCache<NSString, UIImage>`. this object `cacheImage` was initalised in previous view controller and being assigned from pervious to this viewContoller using `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`. when this viewController shows up, I can't see the image in the cell. but i pop the viewController out and segue to this viewController with tableView again. the image will show. I think(I guess) because
the images weren't all fully downloaded yet. so, i can't see the images. but if i pop out the viewController and load an object of viewController and the viewController gets the images from cache. therefore, the images could be shown.

I want to know how to avoid this problem?  thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.content.text = messages[row].content
    cell.date.text = messages[row].createdDateStrInLocal
    cell.messageOwner.text = messages[row].user

    if let avatar = cacheImage.object(forKey: messages[row].user as NSString){
        cell.profileImageView.image = avatar
    } else {
        fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: messages[row].user, handler: { [unowned self] urlStr in
            if let url = URL(string: urlStr), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let avatar = UIImage(data: data){
                self.cacheImage.setObject(avatar, forKey: self.messages[row].user as NSString)

                cell.profileImageView.image = avatar
            }
        })
    }
    return cell
}

fileprivate func fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: String, handler: @escaping (String) -> Void){
    guard !avatarName.isEmpty, let user = self.user, !user.isEmpty else { return }
    let url = URL(string: self.url + "/userAvatarURL")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let body = "username=" + user + "&avatarName=" + avatarName
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody =  body.data(using: .utf8)
    defaultSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode {
                    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if let urlStr = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8), urlStr != "NULL" {
                        handler(urlStr)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if let unwrappedData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                        print("POST: \(unwrappedData)")
                        self.warning(title: "Fail", message: unwrappedData, buttonTitle: "OK", style: .default)
                    } else {
                        self.warning(title: "Fail", message: "unknown error.", buttonTitle: "OK", style: .default)
                    }
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

I modified it, and move the download code in viewdidload and reload the tableview, the result is the same.

Comment: `fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: handler: (String) -> Void)` is the `handler:` closure in main thread?

Comment: I think you need to reload the cell after getting the avatar. I would recommend looking into SDWebImage.

Comment: i added more detail.

Comment: but where should i add reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your image view have a fixed size, or are you taking advantage of the intrinsic size? Based upon your description, I'd assume the latter. And updating the cache and reloading the cell inside `fetchUserAvatar` completion handler should resolve that problem.

But you have two issues here:

1. You should really use `dataTask` to retrieve the image, not `Data(contentsOf:)` because the former is asynchronous and the latter is synchronous. And you never want to do synchronous calls on the main queue. At best, the smoothness of your scrolling will be adversely affected by this synchronous network call. At worst, you risk having the watch dog process kill your app if the network request is slowed down for any reason and you block the main thread at the wrong time.

   Personally, I'd have `fetchUserAvatar` do this second asynchronous request asynchronously and change the closure to return the `UIImage` rather than the URL as a `String`.

   Perhaps something like:

   ```
   fileprivate func fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: String, handler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void){
       guard !avatarName.isEmpty, let user = self.user, !user.isEmpty else {
           handler(nil)
           return
       }

       let url = URL(string: self.url + "/userAvatarURL")!
       var request = URLRequest(url: url)
       let body = "username=" + user + "&avatarName=" + avatarName
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       request.httpBody =  body.data(using: .utf8)

       defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
           guard let data = data, error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
               print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
               DispatchQueue.main.async { handler(nil) }
               return
           }

           guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), let imageURL = URL(string: string) else {
               DispatchQueue.main.async { handler(nil) }
               return
           }

           defaultSession.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (data, response, error) in
               guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                   DispatchQueue.main.async { handler(nil) }
                   return
               }

               let image = UIImage(data: data)
               DispatchQueue.main.async { handler(image) }
           }.resume()
       }.resume()
   }
   ```
2. This is a more subtle point, but you should not use the `cell` inside the asynchronously called completion handler closure. The cell could have scrolled out of view and you could be updating the cell for a different row of the table. This is likely only to be problematic for really slow network connections, but it's still an issue.

   Your asynchronous closure should be determining the index path of the cell and then reloading just that index path with [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows).

   For example:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
       let row = indexPath.row

       cell.content.text = messages[row].content
       cell.date.text = messages[row].createdDateStrInLocal
       cell.messageOwner.text = messages[row].user

       if let avatar = cacheImage.object(forKey: messages[row].user as NSString){
           cell.profileImageView.image = avatar
       } else {
           cell.profileImageView.image = nil   // make sure to reset this first, in case cell is reused
           fetchUserAvatar(avatarName: messages[row].user) { [unowned self] avatar in
               guard let avatar = avatar else { return }
               self.cacheImage.setObject(avatar, forKey: self.messages[row].user as NSString)

               // note, if it's possible rows could have been inserted by the time this async request is done,
               // you really should recalculate what the indexPath for this particular message. Below, I'm just
               // using the previous indexPath, which is only valid if you _never_ insert rows.

               tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
           }
       }

       return cell
   }
   ```

Frankly, there are other subtle issues here (e.g. if your username or avatar name contain reserved characters, your requests will fail; if you scroll quickly on a really slow connection, images for visible cells will get backlogged behind cells that are no longer visible, you risk timeouts, etc.). Rather than spending a lot of time contemplating how to fix these more subtle issues, you might consider using an established `UIImageView` category that performs asynchronous image requests and supports caching. Typical options include AlamofireImage, KingFisher, SDWebImage, etc.

Comment: sorry, the first point i don't really understand. as you said fetching image in `fetchUserAvatar`, so two requests in the method?

Comment: @CarlHung - Yes, two requests, one to get the URL and one to get the image. Ideally, if you could change your web service to just return the actual image as part of the original request, that would be more efficient. But as you've got the web service designed now, with one request for the URL which you then have to subsequently retrieve in another request, then, yes, you should have `fetchUserAvatar` perform both requests. See examples in revised answer above.

Comment: i rewrote the method and download the images using this new method in ViewDidLoad. it is the same. can't fix it. i need to pop the VC and segue it again. then, i will see it.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`? Generally we advise lazy fetch of images (in `cellForRowAt`). I can't comment on your attempt in `viewDidLoad` without seeing what you did. How do you trigger the reload of the relevant cells when `viewDidLoad` finished getting the relevant image?

Comment: oh.i misunderstood the thing. i thought "get backlogged" meant better fetching it in somewhere else. i put the code back to tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:) it works. although  i encountered layout problem. this is another thing. thanks.